# How common is CTE in normal adults?

Tags: brain, neurology, head-trauma, traumatic-encephalopathy

How common is chronic traumatic encephalopathy (CTE) in normal adults who don't have obvious risk factors such as high-impact sports? Have there been any studies done on the normal population as opposed to those who are at risk? (I understand that this can only be diagnosed posthumously, so any study would tend to be biased towards elderly individuals.)